# How to design a method that can deal with two different object types

Tags: java

I have two collections, that have almost similar attributes:

```
HashSet<BuyerUser>
HashSet<SellerUser>
```

I want to write a method that serializes the objects as JSON and sends it to a web API. My problem is, however, that i'm not able to write a method that is generic enough so that I don't have to repeat the code twice.

```
public void addToMetadata (Object users) {

   if (users instanceof BuyerUser) {
        // Do this

    }
    if (users instanceof SellerUser) {
        // Do that

    }
}
```

My problem is the instanceOf check that doesn't work the way I outlined it. I would have to do something like

```
if (users instanceof HashSet<BuyerUser>)
```

but that gives me an error:

```
llegal generic type for instanceof
```

Can that be solved in any way?

Comment: To understand this right: Those two classes have very similar attributes, but _not_ a common superclass, is that correct?

Comment: It really depends on what you do with them. Is it reasonable to have them both extends some base type, User, or implement some common interface, CommercialUser?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to know the type for json serialization? Most(maybe even all?) libraries for dealing with json are working with `Object` when serializing to json.

Comment: Not sure of the efficiency, but you could loop over the HashSet and check the type inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the parameterized type is lost on runtime, you cannot do it.
You can either create a wrapper for each `HashSet` and add a method to it which returns the type:

```
public class MySet<T> extends HashSet<T> {
     private Class<T> type;

     public MySet(Class<T> c) {
          this.type = c;
     }

     public Class<T> getType() {
          return type;
     }
}
```

Or you can get the first element of the set and check the type of that:

```
if(set instanceof HashSet && !set.isEmpty() && set.iterator().next() instanceof BuyerUser) {
    // BuyerUser set
}
```

Be aware the `set` may contain different types of objects like if it was defined as `HashSet<Object>`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (users instanceof HashSet<BuyerUser>)
```

You cannot do this, as generics are erased at runtime when the instanceof call is run

Instead, the better way to go would get to create either a parent class of BuyerUser and SellerUser or an interface that both BuyUser and SellerUser have that has a function like

```
public String toJSON ()
```